# How to document a parameter that expects a constant

Tags: php, phpdoc

What's the recommended way to document function or method parameters whose value is expected to be a predefined constant? So far, I use the data type of the constant and I add a little explanation later.

E.g.:

```
<?php

class Foo{
    const METHOD_GET = 'get';
    const METHOD_POST = 'post';

    /**
     * Load a new foo
     *
     * @param string $method HTTP method to use (either Foo::METHOD_GET or Foo::METHOD_POST)
     */
    public function load($method=Foo::METHOD_POST){
        // ...
    }

    /**
     * Sort current foo
     *
     * @param int $sort_order Sort order (either SORT_ASC or SORT_DESC)
     */
    public function sort($sort_order=SORT_ASC){
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: looks fine to me as is, though I'd probably would rather have two methods `post()` and `get()` and sortAsc() and `sortDesc()` or make the http request and sorting strategies external objects passable to Foo.

Comment: Here's a discussion on this topic: https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/issues/557

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that you can use a known class as the dataype in param and return tags, I would also expect that you can use a known constant.  When you want to specify multiple type options, you just delimit the list with pipes.  Modifying your example:

```
/**
 * Load a new foo
 *
 * @param Foo::METHOD_GET|Foo::METHOD_POST $method HTTP method to use
 */
public function load($method=Foo::METHOD_POST){
    // ...
}
```

Since the datatype in this case is a known *internal-to-the-class* value, it might even work without the classname prefix:

```
* @param METHOD_GET|METHOD_POST $method HTTP method to use
```

Comment: I've been testing with a couple of IDEs and phpDocumentor itself. Apparently, none of them will do anything special with the param type (such as creating links or feeding the autocomplete list). So I guess there is no standard way to do it and whatever method I choose will do no harm. I'll consider your idea.

Answer (score 6):

## #1: PHPStorm-only option, available in all PHP versions

While non-canonical, it's currently possible to achieve auto-completion with a list of options for a param inside PHPStorm, in case it's common in your team. It uses the new PHP8 Annotations, but PHP8 is not required - since the objective is just to parse the source and get auto-completion.

Since it's (unfortunately) not part of the official PHPDoc standard, it gets a bit ugly for simple methods since you need a full (and maybe long) extra line to properly document the options, but it's still better than no docs.

See [their official post on the topic](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2020/10/phpstorm-2020-3-eap-4/#expectedvalues), but here's an example from the same post:

[image]

## #2: PHP-wide option, but only from 8.1 up

PHP 8.1 will feature Enums, which are the "official" version of value lists. Enums can be used as the type of a param, and this would solve the same issue we're having, in an official way and that PHPDoc can support without including new syntaxes - and also actually enforcing the param check during runtime! You can see more how that would work in [another PHPStorm post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2021/07/phpstorm-2021-2-release/#enums) (no affiliation at all, I just happened to discover the feature through them, so I'm honoring the source).